# Understanding EntityAutocomplete::validateEntityAutocomplete

Tags: 8, entities, ajax

I am trying to understand the code in [`EntityAutocomplete::validateEntityAutocomplete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Element%21EntityAutocomplete.php/function/EntityAutocomplete%3A%3AvalidateEntityAutocomplete/8.2.x).

```
if ($match !== NULL) {
  $value[] = array(
    'target_id' => $match,
  );
}
elseif ($autocreate) {
  /** @var  Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityReferenceSelection\SelectionWithAutocreateInterface $handler */
  // Auto-create item. See an example of how this is handled in
  // \Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem::presave().
  $value[] = array(
    'entity' => $handler->createNewEntity($element['#target_type'], $element['#autocreate']['bundle'], $input, $element['#autocreate']['uid']),
  );
}
```

What is `$handler->createNewEntity()` actually doing?

Does it directly create a new entity in database? If the answer is *yes*, why is the entity created during validation? What is the purpose of this?

Still in [`validateEntityAutocomplete`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Element%21EntityAutocomplete.php/function/EntityAutocomplete%3A%3AvalidateEntityAutocomplete/8.2.x) if you scroll further down, you can see:

```
$valid_ids = $handler->validateReferenceableEntities($ids);
```

```
$valid_new_entities = $handler->validateReferenceableNewEntities($new_entities);
```

I understand that one is validating the ID and the other one is validating `$newEntities`, but what exactly does it do?

Comment: Not a full answer, but the create method on entities (pattern since Drupal 7) create an entity object, but does not call the save method on it. The comment in the first code snippet directs you to how autocreate is used which is in the presave method for entity reference field type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, are you saying that the method is just to create an entity object, without saving it first? what the purpose of that? why don't they just save it during form submit?

Comment: The pattern is to load it into form state so that there's a chance some other actor may want to run further validation or modification during submit (or process if that pattern still exists). Then, it should be saved during form submit.